# When I log in to the Cloud foundry (Authenticating... {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"User authentication failed: unauthorized"})

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-business-application-studio

I am inside the SAP Business Application Studio, inside the terminal, when I put the CF login command I enter my credentials and this appears

Authenticating...
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"User authentication failed: Unauthorized"}

Could you please help me

Comment: do you have news about the error?

Comment: the same here, I already contacted SAP support. Let's see when they reply.

Answer (score 2):

The solution on my side is to use the `--sso` option.

`cf login --sso -a https://api.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com`

Afterwards you will be prompted to get a passcode from this url: `https://login.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com/passcode`

However, for me this failed several times.
The key is to use alternative identity provider on the login screen
and enter `sap.ids` as provider when you already have an SAP Universal login

[image]

Sadly, this does not work when using trial version in API endpoint `https://api.cf.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com` . I already opened a support request.